# How do I re-download songs I purchased on the iPad, after formatting the iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, ios-appstore, music

I formatted the iPad and lost my songs.

Is it possible to re-download songs I bought via iPad?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the purchased tab in the app stores should allow you to re-download most if not all of your purchases. If you have previously hidden some purchases, you may need to access your Apple store account (Apple ID) to see the unfiltered list of past purchases.

Please see [this link](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2011/07/download-previously-purchased-songs-apps-and-books.html) or [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on Apple's website for more details. You can edit your question or ask another if you find a problem on a specific step.

Comment: @MaxRied Nopes. iCloud. iTunes Match is a subscription only service. It may use the same technology underneath (who knows!) but this feature has been available since they launched iCloud. For more details see [this](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/).

Comment: So if I did not have iCloud when I purchased the songs I am doomed? Is this logical?

Comment: @p.a. Don't think so. When I moved to iOS 5, I noticed that all my purchases were there. Give it a shot, if it does not work you don't lose anything anyway.

Comment: I dont doubt iCloud is superb. However, I lost my songs 3 months ago and I didnt have iCloud back then so...

Comment: @p.a. Any song you purchased from iTunes **at any time in the past** should now be available for re-download via your iTunes account regardless of your use of any other iCloud feature, or iTunes Match subscription (there may be some exceptions, such as songs no longer available in the iTunes store). If the songs you lost were never purchased from iTunes, however (such as tracks ripped from a CD), then you will have to restore them from elsewhere yourself.